# How can I set a script time out value in Webdriver JS?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am creating a webdriver instance with:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox())
                    .build();
```

Then try to set scriptTimeOut with

```
driver.Timeouts.setScriptTimeout(30);
```

But webdriver errors with:

> driver.Timeouts.setScriptTimeout(30);
>   TypeError: Cannot call method 'setScriptTimeout' of undefined

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `manage().timeouts()`:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(value);
```